# Normal map edges looks jagged and faded

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking, normal-map, bevel

I have a model which I want to bake bevels in, I literary duplicate the object, add bevels unto the newly created object.

I bake it with cycles, yet the edges always look like this, no matter how I try using a cage, adding supporting loops in the low poly, checking the shading

nothing worked, i made sure the nodes are non-color.

**Am I missing something ?**

[image]

Edit: I added a pic of the nodes for more clarity.

[image]

Edit : I added a pic of the cage, I just duplicated the low poly and added a displace modifier , tweaked it a bit for better proximity. I also tried using displace modifier on the beveled object to make sure it's slightly above the low poly so the latter's edges won't pop out of the bevels, yet nothing made a difference.

[image]

Comment: is in 2.7xx or 2.8 ?

Comment: include a screenshot of your nodes may be easier to identify where the error is

Comment: its 2.8 . the latest stable version